# Partial template specialization array usage

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I've been trying to distinguish cases when the argument passed to constructor is an array or a simple pointer. So, I write this example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// here I create a structure which I intend to use 
// to tell arrays from non-arrays.

template<typename T>
struct TypeTraits {
  static bool const IsArray = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct TypeTraits<T[]> {
  static bool const IsArray = true;
};

// And here I create a container to store a pointer.

template<typename TValue>
class Ptr_container {
  TValue * ptr;
public:
  template<typename T>
  explicit Ptr_container(T from_ptr) :
    ptr (from_ptr)
  {
    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << TypeTraits<T>::IsArray << endl;
    cout << "Just to be sure: " << std::is_array<T>::value << endl;
  }
  ~Ptr_container()
  {
    delete ptr;
  }
};

int main () {
  Ptr_container<int> a (new int(2));
  Ptr_container<int> b (new int[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

And the result is false/false. So, I'm obviously doing something wrong, and the question is, what should I do to distinguish cases when new memory was allocated using **new T** and **new T[N]** ?

**Update:** I've added an "arrayness" check using `std::is_array`, but it wouldn't change the result.
There must be some way to detect "arrayness" during compile-time, because of following: `boost::shared_ptr` takes a pointer as an argument to constructor and its inner structures are initialized somehow using only that information. And somewhere inside `boost::shared_ptr` class there is a structure which decides how to delete memory pointed by `shared_ptr` (using `delete` or `delete[]`).

Actually, I'm trying to implement some part of `shared_ptr`, but I'm failing at the stage of array recognition.

**Update 2** I've finally got it figured out, so I'm closing the question. The solution to the problem was to add another parameter to the template and do the initialization of container in the way like

```
Ptr_container<int, PointerProperty> pa (new int(4));
Ptr_container<int, ArrayProperty> pv (new int[4]);
```

Comment: `new` and `new[]` return a pointer. That pointer contains nothing but the address of the newly allocated memory, no size information and so on, so `typeof (new int) == typeof (new int[]) == int *`. However, I believe that you're trying to achieve what both `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector` already provide.

Comment: Dude, `std::is_array`...

Comment: @KerrekSB If new[] returns T* (which it does afaik), then std::is_array<T*>::value will always be false, will it not? He'd actually need to pass in something like int[] for the thing to return true.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: yes yes, I was just referring to the wheel-reinvention that was going on in the OP's code.

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr` can only safely hold an array if you put information in the type that it's an array (`boost::shared_ptr<T[]>`, starting with v1.53), or if you provide a custom deleter. Similarly `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, but there's no std-equivalent `std::shared_ptr<T[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely cannot distinguish between pointers returned from `new` and `new[]` at compile-time. Not using templates, or standard type traits with compiler hooks, and not any other technique.

The reason for this should be obvious; if it's not, consider the following code: (things don't work like this; I'm just following your example.)

```
int * p = nullptr;
if (rand() % 2 == 0)
    p = new int;
else
    p = new int [42];

print_is_array (p); // Assume this does the detection and prints something.
```

How could you (and the compiler) know at compile time whether `p` will be allocated using `new` or `new[]`?

Also, what you call "array" is more properly known as "*vector*" (not to be confused with `std::vector`.) Arrays have some compile-time properties (like size) that run-time-allocated blocks of memory don't, even if you happen to construct multiple objects in them (e.g. with `new[]`.)

And, passing an array of `T`s (a real, proper, compile-time array) into a function that accepts `T *`s will "*decay*" the type and lose the "arrayness". I'm referring here to the way you've defined your constructor, namely it taking a `T *`.

If you are curious to see how to detect (proper) arrays at compile-time, take a look at the implementation of `std::is_array<T>` template in the `<type_traits>` header.

EDIT: By the way, this is what I mean when I say (proper) array:

```
int a [42];
```

not this:

```
int * p = new int [42];
```

These are two different types, but the first one can "decay" and be implicitly cast into the second type.

Comment: What you're saying is that both `new` and `new[]` return `T*` :).

Comment: Of course it is. I thought the OP might want some kind of rationale to go with it (however badly presented and explained!) :D

Comment: I just think it's always a good idea to think statically first before even bothering with runtime. Both new and new[] return T*, there is no hidden difference between them, it's all in the signature, hence you can't really differentiate. Your insta-nullptr though is a nice touch! :)

Comment: Yep, that seems to answer why my code doesn't work as I intend it to. However, there is a second part of my question: how to implement such recognition? Thanks for the hint, though.

Answer (score 1):

As **Zeta** said in the comment:

```
typeof (new int) == typeof (new int[]) == int *
```

However if you need to distinguish between objects of your classes created with `new` and `new[]`, **overloading** those operators would make more sense.